# find only matching elements from a JSON array in Ne DB/react native-local-mongo/mongo db

Tags: mongodb, react-native, nedb

i am trying to read only matching keys from a JSON with a nested array.
here is my JSON.

```
data:[
{
"locale":"en_US",
"pages":[
   {
     pageName:"testpage1",
     "messages":{
        "m1":"v1",
        "m2":""
      }
   },
{
     pageName:"testpage2",
     "messages":{
        "m1":"v3",
        "m2":"v4"
      }
   }
]
},
{
"locale":"in_L1",
"pages":[
   {
     pageName:"testpage1",
     "messages":{
        "m1":"i1",
        "m2":"i2"
      }
   },
{
     pageName:"testpage2",
     "messages":{
        "m1":"i3",
        "m2":"i4"
      }
   }
]
}
]
```

I am trying the below query:

```
    db['collec1'].find({locale:"en_US", pages:{$elemMatch:{pageName:"testpage1"}, 
            {locale:1,"pages.pageName":1}}})
```

also tried,

```
db['collec1'].find({locale:"en_US", "pages.pageName":"testpage1"},{locale:1,"pages.pageName":1}}})
```

both are returning, the all the elements in the array as below:

```
[
  {
    "locale":"en_US",
    pages:{pageName:["testpage1", "testpage2"]}]
  }
]
```

Expected output is:

```
[
      {
        "locale":"en_US",
        pages:{pageName:["testpage1"]}]
      }
    ]
```

can someone help me where i am doing it wrong and what needs to be changed?
i am using [this](https://github.com/antoniopresto/react-native-local-mongodb) library which is a clone of mongodb called Ne DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
 db['collec1'].find({locale:"en_US", pages:{$elemMatch:{pageName:"testpage1"}}).
```

> try with an empty project in the find method `{}` and then try like
>   the above example

Comment: its returning an error guess {lean:true} is not supported. filtering on locale is happening but its returning all array elements. i need only matching elements from the array. can you help?

Comment: run this query and check again ` db['collec1'].find({locale:"en_US", pages:{$elemMatch:{pageName:"testpage1"}}).
`

Comment: same getting [
  {
    "locale":"en_US",
    pages:{pageName:["testpage1", "testpage2"]}]
  }
]